# Declaring a variable with "class " keyword vs Declaring one without "class" keyword in function signatures

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, syntax-error, keyword

What is the difference between the two methods?

Sometimes when I get compile-time errors complaining that the compiler does not recognize 
some class types in function signatures, then if I add the keyword "class" in front of the respective variables, it can always solve this kind of compile-time errors.

For example, if the compiler does not recognize the type ***Client*** in

```
void recv( Client * c )
```

then if I change it to

```
void recv( class Client * c )
```

the problem is solved.

I am sorry that I cannot come up with a concrete example as I randomly came up with this question.

Comment: Never heard of that. Can you give a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that displays this error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using keyword class, struct, enum in a type parameter declaration is called elaborated type specifier. It introduces the new type in the scope where the function is declared.
It is similar to forward declaration.

There is also another using of such a declaration. For example if a name of an object or a function name hides a class or enum with the same name. For example

```
struct A {};

A A; // now A is seen as an identifier of the object

void f( struct A );
```

Comment: so this in situation, we need the keyword struct in the signature of the function f to differentiate A from the variable name A declared in the second line.

Answer (score 1):

In this case

```
void recv(Client * c)
```

Compiler looks for declaration of `Client`. If it cannot find, it will give error. You can solve it by forward declaration as shown following

```
class Client;
void recv(Client * c)
```

Although I have never seen second case, but it looks like that is also declaring class Client here.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to prefix your parameter with `class`, it means that the compiler is not yet aware of a class called `Client`. Take the following contrived example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   MyClass m;

   return 0;
}

class MyClass
{
};
```

Because `MyClass` is declared AFTER the main function, the main function is not aware of the class called `MyClass` when it tries to create the variable `m`, and your program would refuse to compile.

To solve this, you would typically use a forward declaration:

```
class MyClass; // <-- Forward declare MyClass.

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   MyClass m;

   return 0;
}

class MyClass
{
};
```

In your case, the use of the `class` keyword before the function parameter's type is essentially forward declaring the class name for you.

Comment: so does that means that I could have also forward-declared class Client at the very beginning of the file without having to use elaborated type specifier in the function signature like I did above?

Comment: @takwing - Yes I'd expect so.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler must know the type of the function parameter. Since you obviously don't provide a definition for example by including the header of `Client` you have to provide a forward declaration. That is  what you do in the second example (in an unusual way), so the compiler knows, that Client is a class. Since you only use a Pointer, the declaration is enough and you don't need the definition at this point.